# Setting up a background image in Android Project

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building an Android App using Eclipse. I'm trying to create a simple image display when the application opens.

I've saved my intro_image.png on res\drawable-hdpi in my workspace, I've created another xml for the layout with the following code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/intro_image">

</LinearLayout>
```

An error message appears when I view the result on the Graphical Layout, saying: "Failed to convert @drawable/into_image into a drawable. Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/intro_image"

How do I solve this? 
Thank you.

Comment: Try to clean/build your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to refresh or clean your project. it will work.whenever you paste an image into drawable you have to refresh that folder.